# Delta-v difference between Mars and Moon

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mars, the-moon, delta-v, rocket-equation

Considering a simple Hohmann transfer, does it take less Delta-v and propellant to go to Mars than to the Moon

Comment: How long are you willing to take to get to either location?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Does delta-V depend on duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for a landing.  Moon, 1730 m/s.  Mars requires twice as much, 3800 m/s.
[image]

Comment: Mars does allow aerobraking and chutelanding, so by the delta-V map you've displayed, for a sufficiently light and risky mission, you can put an object on surface of Mars for at total of about 13.7km/s during a Hohmann transfer window, vs 15.1 km/s for a propulsive Moonlanding.

Comment: The one thing that is bugging me about this map: I'd expect the grey link between LEO and Moon Intercept  (3260 m/s on the map) to be pretty close in value, but less than the blue link between LEO and Earth Intercept (3210 m/s.on map) under coplanar/circular orbit simplifications. I wonder if the creator priced in a plane change to the Moon intercept burn.